# Does "schwarzl" also mean black?

Tags: german-to-english, meaning

While driving I noticed there was a lake in Austria called "Schwarzlsee". "Schwarzl" is very similar to "schwarz". Does it also mean black, what is the difference between it and just "schwarz"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Entstanden ist der 56 Hektar große See als eine Schottergrube der **Baufirma Schwarzl Beton** durch Grundwasser geflutet wurde. 1984 konnte das Freizeitzentrum als Nachnutzung des Schottertagebaus eröffnet werden. Es beherbergt neben dem Badesee die sogenannte „Steiermark-Halle“ mit Gastronomiebetrieben und die „Davis-Cup-Halle“, in der regelmäßig der Tennis-Bewerb Davis-Cup gespielt wurde und die als Veranstaltungszentrum verschiedener Art Verwendung findet.

So in this case the name is based on the company name, which in turn is based on the family name / surname "Schwarzl". I don't know of any relation to the colour "schwarz".

Sources

- [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzlsee)
- [Schotter- und Betonwerk Karl Schwarzl](http://www.schotter-betonwerk-schwarzl.at)

Comment: This is rather a guess, but I could very well imagine that "Schwarzl" (with the "l" as diminuitive as "-lein", "le", "li" in other regions) stems from an ancestor working underground, maybe in a coal mine.
Less likely, but not impossible, may be a connection to hunting boars (also called "Schwarzröcke") or some family trait like unusually dark hair in an environment where people had rather bright hair colours.

Answer (score 8):

Appending an "*L*" to the end of a word is a way of forming a diminuative frequently used in Austria/Southern Germany (don't know about other regions).

Another example are the quite common names

> Schmiedl / Schmied

Or the word

> Stiegl (from Stiege)

which is also the name of a successful brand of beer from Salzburg.

As @Baz has already pointed out correctly, the name of the lake derives from a (fairly common) family name.

Comment: It is the same as the high German "-lein". In other dialects it's "-li" (Swiss-German) or "-le" (Baden dialect). So a little dog is a "Hündlein" in high German, a "Hündli" in Switzerland and a "Hündle" in Baden-Wuerttemberg.

Answer (score 1):

Die Schwarzlteiche waren früher Schotterteiche der Firma Schwarzl. Sie entstanden durch Ausbaggern des Schotters der für die Bauindustrie benötigt wurde. Das Grundwasser füllte die Gruben zu Teichen auf.

Das Areal der Firma Schwarzl liegt zwischen dem militärischen Fliegerhorst Nittner (einem der zwei Standort an dem die Militärflugzeuge Österreichs stationiert sind) bzw. dem zivilen Flughafen Graz-Thalerhof und der Autobahn A9. Früher wurde dort illegal und meist nackt gebadet, später erfolgte die Nutzung ganz offiziell gegen Eintrittsgeld. Als die offizielle Nutzung als Badesee begann wurden die zuvor voneinander getrennten Teiche zu einem größeren Gewässer mit mehreren Ausbuchtungen verbunden. Nacktbaden ist nur mehr an der nördlichen Bucht des Sees erlaubt. Da diese Bucht sehr groß ist ist dieser Teil des Sees trotzdem das größte FKK-Gebiet der Steiermark.

---

»Schwarzl« ist in der Steiermark ein sehr häufiger Familienname. Ich bin dort geboren und aufgewachsen und kenne mehrere Menschen dieses Namens.

Der Name »Schwarzl» ist abgeleitet vom Familiennamen »Schwarz«, der in dieser Region ebenfalls sehr häufig ist. Das Anhängen eines »l« an einen Namen geschieht im Südosten Österreichs häufig, jedoch meist an Vornamen von Kindern. »Kurtl« ist ein kleiner Bub der Kurt heißt. Ebenso »Ernstl« (kleiner Ernst), »Bertl« (kleiner Robert, Herbert, Hubert, ...), »Franzl« (kleiner Franz), »Gustl« (kleiner August). Das findet man auch bei Mädchennamen, wobei hier das a durch ein l ersetzt wird: »Lisl«, »Christl«, usw.

Der Name »Schwarz« wiederum steht mit der Farbe vermutlich in einem ähnlichen Zusammenhang wie die Familiennamen »Weiß«, »Roth«, »Braun« usw. Diese Namen haben in den meisten Fällen jüdische Wurzeln. Sie gehen auf die Farben der Fahnen der zwölf Söhne Israels zurück:

- Schwarz: Joseph und Benjamin
- Roth: Ruben
- Weiß: Zebulon
- Grün: Simeon
- usw.

Häufig findet man diese Farben auch als Bestandteil zusammengesetzter Namen:
Grünspan, Bleiweiß, Lichtblau, ...